# Transclude example not working for me

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been taking a look for [this tutorial](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html), and now I'm trying to follow it. But somehow, when I reach the following JSBin and paste it all on my test folder, it just won't work:

http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html

You can see at the right side the card showing up perfectly. Well, when I copy paste this code, the content doesn't get rendered inside the "content" div of the template, which means that transclusion isn't working at all.

What may be happening? The code is perfectly pasted, both HTML, CSS and JS. Even tried with my local version of Angular (last one).

But the content keeps being hidden! Any help with this? I really wanna learn how the transclusion works.

Comment: Are there any error messages on the console? You should try posting a link to your broken jsbin copy (ie. your actual code), not the blog you're basing it on - we can't guess what you might have done wrong, we need to see your code.

Comment: I understand your point, but my code is actually the same than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider I have created a directive called myDirective as an element

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <my-directive>
      <button>some button</button>
      <a href="#">and a link</a>
   </my-directive>
</div>
```

myDirective has a template which is using transclude

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
   return{
     restrict: 'E',
     transclude: true,
     template: '<div class="something" ng-transclude> my directive goes here...</div>'
  }
});
```

It will render the DOM as

```
<div class="something"> 
   my directive goes here...
   <button>some button</button>
   <a href="#">and a link</a>
</div>.
```

Comment: Hm, I really prefer this example, it's really well explained, and short. So double good!